# Export class from files other than index.ts

Tags: assemblyscript

I made a file called `assembly/Vec3.ts` with this content:

```
/**
 * @constructor
 * @name pc.Vec3
 * @classdesc A 3-dimensional vector.
 * @description Creates a new Vec3 object.
 * @param {Number} [x] The x value. If x is an array of length 3, the array will be used to populate all components.
 * @param {Number} [y] The y value.
 * @param {Number} [z] The z value.
 * @example
 * var v = new pc.Vec3(1, 2, 3);
 */
export class Vec3 {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    z: number;

    // AS is more strict than TS... need to replace all occuranves of this in PlayCanvasTS at some point
    //constructor(x?: any, y?: number, z?: number)
    constructor(x: number, y: number, z: number)
    {
        //if (x && x.length === 3) {
        //  this.x = x[0];
        //  this.y = x[1];
        //  this.z = x[2];
        //} else {
        //  this.x = x || 0;
        //  this.y = y || 0;
        //  this.z = z || 0;
        //}
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    /**
     * @function
     * @name pc.Vec3#add
     * @description Adds a 3-dimensional vector to another in place.
     * @param {pc.Vec3} rhs The vector to add to the specified vector.
     * @returns {pc.Vec3} Self for chaining.
     * @example
     * var a = new pc.Vec3(10, 10, 10);
     * var b = new pc.Vec3(20, 20, 20);
     *
     * a.add(b);
     *
     * // Should output [30, 30, 30]
     * console.log("The result of the addition is: " + a.toString());
     */
    add(rhs: Vec3): Vec3 {
        this.x += rhs.x;
        this.y += rhs.y;
        this.z += rhs.z;

        return this;
    }

    /**
     * @function
     * @name pc.Vec3#add2
     * @description Adds two 3-dimensional vectors together and returns the result.
     * @param {pc.Vec3} lhs The first vector operand for the addition.
     * @param {pc.Vec3} rhs The second vector operand for the addition.
     * @returns {pc.Vec3} Self for chaining.
     * @example
     * var a = new pc.Vec3(10, 10, 10);
     * var b = new pc.Vec3(20, 20, 20);
     * var r = new pc.Vec3();
     *
     * r.add2(a, b);
     * // Should output [30, 30, 30]
     *
     * console.log("The result of the addition is: " + r.toString());
     */
    add2(lhs: Vec3, rhs: Vec3): Vec3 {
        this.x = lhs.x + rhs.x;
        this.y = lhs.y + rhs.y;
        this.z = lhs.z + rhs.z;

        return this;
    }
}
```

Then building it via `npm run asbuild`

But the file is just ignored and not included inside the `untouched.wasm`.

Is it possible to export classes from all files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently AssemblyScript support global export only from entry file (`index.ts`). So you should reexport all your entities to this file. But this may improve in future. See this discussion: https://github.com/AssemblyScript/assemblyscript/issues/464

Answer (score 0):

Currently I solved it by adding the `Vec3.ts` to `asc` in `doit.sh`:

```
# print the commands via -x/+y
set -x
npx asc assembly/index.ts assembly/Vec3.ts -b build/untouched.wasm -t build/untouched.wat --sourceMap --validate --debug
npx asc assembly/index.ts assembly/Vec3.ts -b build/optimized.wasm -t build/optimized.wat --sourceMap --validate --optimize
set +x
```